# ¿El resultado es incorrecto con Numpy en Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matemáticas, numpy

Estaba realizando unos ejercicios de matrices con numpy, pero al parecer generó un error en la respuesta final:

[image: Código ejecutado]

Como podemos observar el resultado final de `Z*Z` es:

```
[[9,4,1],
[1,0,1],
[1,4,9],]
```

Pero tras una sospecha comparé los resultados a mano con Mathcad y el resultado es:

```
[[10,4,-2],[4,4,4],[-2,4,10]]
```

el código para que lo comprueben es:

```
from numpy import array
X=array([[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1]])
Y=array([[-2,-2,-2],[0,0,0],[2,2,2]])
Z=X+Y
Z=Z*Z
print(Z)
```

Numpy ¿generó un error o para calcular el producto de matrices es otro comando?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que estás haciendo no es un producto de matrices. Para hacer producto de matrices tienes que usar `numpy.dot` o el método `dot` de un *numpy array*. Además, desde la salida de la versión 3.5 de Python puedes hacer uso del nuevo operador `@` para hacer producto de matrices.

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1]])
Y = np.array([[-2,-2,-2],[0,0,0],[2,2,2]])
Z = X + Y
Z = np.dot(Z, Z)
print(Z)

# alternativas
# Z = Z.dot(Z)
# Z = Z @ Z # a partir de Python 3.5
```

Y el resultado del `print` es:

```
[[10  4 -2]
 [ 4  4  4]
 [-2  4 10]]
```

Comment: Una pregunta: al utilizar `Z*Z` ¿qué operación realizó en realidad?

Comment: Realiza la multiplicación elemento a elemento. No es una multiplicación matricial. Si los arrays que se multiplican no tienen la misma forma numpy realiza una cosa que se llama *broadcasting*: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: Gracias @kikocorreoso!

Comment: Gracias kikocorreoso, excelente, sí funcionó con .dot.